# Javascript Lotto number checker

Tags: javascript

Hi I am new to Javascript and am trying to do a number checker program.

the customer number is 12 and is within the winning numbers.

This seems to work and print it is a winning number but if I change the value to say 13 it still prints the winning number.

Like the document.write is printing regardless of the fact it is in an if statement.

Any help or guidance would be appreciated

Thanks

Here is my code

```
 var customerNumbers = 12;

    //Array stating the winning numbers

    var winningNumbers = [12, 17, 24, 37, 38, 43];



    document.write("<h1>This Weeks Winning Numbers are:</h1>");

    //For statement to list ALL values in the winning numbers array 

    for (var i=0;i<winningNumbers.length;i++)

    {

    document.write(winningNumbers[i] + "&#44; &#32;");

    }


    document.write("<h1>The Customer's Number is:</h1>");

    document.write(customerNumbers);



    //if statement to check if customer number matches with winning numbers

    if (customerNumbers == 12 || 17 || 24 || 37 || 38 || 43)

    {
  document.write("<h3>We have a match and a winner!</h3>");
  }



    else if (customerNumbers !== 12 || 17 || 24 || 37 || 38 || 43)
  {
  document.write("<h4>Sorry you are not a winner this week</h4>");
  }


    else (customerNumbers !== 12 || 17 || 24 || 37 || 38 || 43)
  {
  document.write("<h4>Sorry you are not a winner this week</h4>");
  }
```

Comment: What have you researched and tried so far to fix your error?

Answer (score 3):

Your error is in the If and Else statements

```
customerNumbers == 12 || 17 || 24 || 37 || 38 || 43
```

the above does not work as you're expecting, replace it with

```
customerNumbers == 12 ||  customerNumbers == 17 ||  customerNumbers == 24 ||   customerNumbers == 37 ||  customerNumbers == 38 ||  customerNumbers == 43
```

more clean:

```
winningNumbers.indexOf(customerNumbers) > -1
```

Comment: works perfectly now, thanks so much! I didnt realise you had to repeat the variable for each OR

Answer (score 0):

The code,

```
customerNumbers == 12 || 17 || 24 || 37 || 38 || 43
```

will check if the customerNumbers is equal to 12 if not it will assign to it 17 and that will pass the if statement as true.

So you need to check if the array contains the customerNumbers by something else like,

```
if(winningNumbers.indexOf(customerNumbers)!=-1)
```